# Portfolio Risk Contribution

Tags: finance, portfolio-optimization, risk

I came across a paper that shows calculations for two types of portfolio risk contribution. The first shows "Asset risk contributions" and the second shows "Correlation-weighted asset risk contributions" as so:

$I \times (W \times (V \times C \times V \times w))$

and

$C \times (W \times (V \times C \times V \times w)$, respectively where:

```
x denotes matrix multiplication
I is the identity matrix
W is the diagonal matrix of asset weights
V is the diagonal matrix of asset volatilities
C is the asset correlation matrix
w is the vector of asset weights
```

Unfortunately, after playing around with these two formulas with dummy data, I was not able to see anything that looked like a "risk contribution". A risk contribution should represent a percentage of total portfolio volatility and all risk contributions should add to 100%. Can anyone provide guidance on how these formulas can be modified to achieve their intention?

Thank you.

Comment: To me, this question seems to have more to do with how financiers might quantitatively measure risk than it does a statistical topic. Would you like me to migrate it to quant.SE for you?

Comment: Sure. Thank you.

Comment: Would be mind refrence the paper?

Comment: Here is a link to the paper on my dropbox. I could not find it anywhere on the web anymore. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr7cifqmlo8yb17/SU830-1%281%29.pdf?dl=0